# Hive queries failing with "Unable to fetch table test_table. Invalid method name: 'get_table_req'" with pyspark 3.0.0 & Hive 1.1.0

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hive, cloudera

Digging into a POC for spark in a fairly new environment and checking spark capabilities but Having issues with running sql queries in pyspark terminal whereas Hive is working since we can query metadata.

Any idea whats happening here and how to resolve this?

```
$ pyspark --driver-class-path /etc/spark2/conf:/etc/hive/conf
>>> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
>>> from pyspark.sql import Row
>>> spark = SparkSession \
...     .builder \
...     .appName("sample_query_test") \
... .enableHiveSupport() \
...     .getOrCreate()
>>> spark.sql("show tables in user_tables").show(5)
20/08/18 19:57:01 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.enforce.sorting does not exist
20/08/18 19:57:01 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.enforce.bucketing does not exist
20/08/18 19:57:01 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
|   database|           tableName|isTemporary|
+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
|user_tables|              a_2019|      false|
|user_tables|abcdefgjeufjdsahh...|      false|
|user_tables|testtesttesttestt...|      false|
|user_tables|newnewnewnewnenwn...|      false|
|user_tables|blahblahblablahbl...|      false|
+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
only showing top 5 rows

>>> spark.sql("select count(*) from user_tables.test_table where date_partition='2020-08-17'").show(5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 646, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 137, in deco
    raise_from(converted)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
**pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to fetch table test_spark_cedatatransfer. Invalid method name: 'get_table_req';**
```

Information on the cluster :

```
$ hive --version
Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.13.0
Subversion file:///data/jenkins/workspace/generic-package-ubuntu64-16-04/CDH5.13.0-Packaging-Hive-2017-10-04_10-50-44/hive-1.1.0+cdh5.13.0+1269-1.cdh5.13.0.p0.34~xenial -r Unknown
Compiled by jenkins on Wed Oct 4 11:46:53 PDT 2017

$ pyspark --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.0.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.12.10, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_252
Branch HEAD
Compiled by user ubuntu on 2020-06-06T11:32:25Z
Revision 3fdfce3120f307147244e5eaf46d61419a723d50
Url https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf/spark.git

$ hadoop version
Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.13.0
Subversion http://github.com/cloudera/hadoop -r 42e8860b182e55321bd5f5605264da4adc8882be
Compiled by jenkins on 2017-10-04T18:50Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 5e84c185f8a22158e2b0e4b8f85311
This command was run using /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.13.0.jar
```

As its evident, I added hive conf to make sure same metastore is being used and while simple queries working the insert overwrite is failing!

Comment: I don't think CDH supports Spark 3, yet. Plus, Spark 3 probably uses a higher version of Hive itself

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have shared the environment details, can you suggest correct pyspark version or workaround ? Will try to communicate with cluster admins for necessary changes if its imperative

Comment: As of CDH 6, Spark 2 is included, [according to documentation](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/spark.html).

Comment: we have cdh 5.13.0 which comes with spark 1.6.0 > so which pyspark should be ideal? (from versions: 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.2.0.post0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.4.5, 2.4.6, 3.0.0)

Comment: None... You need to download Spark 1.6 separarely since you cannot `pip install` versions lower than 2.1.2

Answer (score 2):

I have run into the same issue, trying to use Spark 3.0.1 with HDP2.6.

Problem was resolved by removing all `hive*.jar` files from `jars` folder, and copying `hive*jar` from Spark2, shipped with HDP distribution.

Comment: is there a compatibility chart for what version of spark is compatible with which version of pyspark and hive? that would be great to get the best out of the environment

Answer (score 0):

Setting the following properties in spark-defaults.conf have worked for me:

```
spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars=maven
spark.sql.hive.metastore.version=1.2.1

spark.sql.catalogImplementation=hive
spark.sql.warehouse.dir=/user/hive/warehouse
```

Of course the last line may be customized, to the appropriate location. This path is for Cloudera (CDH).

These settings will instruct Spark to download and cache jar files in ~/.ivy2/jars for Hive 1.2.1. You may also choose to provide your own jars in an own path, but maven yield the most comfortable option.

See [Spark configuartion properties](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#static-sql-configuration) for more details!